# How change the background color of Unicodes Symbols in a R plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to change the background color of a unicode Symbol in a R base plot. Here an example:

```
plot(x, y,  pch = -as.hexmode("2603"), main = "Corte 1", cex = 3, bg = "purple", col = "black")
```

I was trying to change the background color with the `bg` command, but it works only for "normal" `pch` symbols. Do you know if it is possible? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
par(bg="purple")
plot(x, y,  pch = -as.hexmode("2603"), main = "Corte 1", cex = 3, col = "black")
```

If you want more control, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236958/change-background-color-of-r-plot)