# How to change the background color of a plot generated by a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app that generates a plot after pressing a button, I want the user to be able to manually change the background of the plot generated but I can't seem to get the color to change after the plot is created the first time.

I'm using RStudio 1.1.45 and Shiny 1.2

Here's an example of what I thought would work:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel('Changing Plot background color in shiny'),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                colourInput('background.color','Select Background Color','white'),
                tags$hr(),
                actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
            ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot",width = "500px", height="500px") ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    isolate({
        input$goButton
        bg.col = input$background.color
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            plot(sample(1:10,10))
            },
            res = 72, bg = bg.col)
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The expected result would be for the background color of the whole plot to change after the user manually selects a hex value from the color palette.

Comment: Does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236958/change-background-color-of-r-plot

Comment: My Shiny is pretty rusty, but I'm pretty sure that putting  `input$goButton` *inside* `isolate` is wrong. See, e.g., [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html) where `input$goButton` is not inside `isolate()`.